# Get Exception when showing Alert Dialog from Service - Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application

Tags: android, android-service

Get Exception when showing Alert Dialog from Service.

Following is the code in my Service class: I am trying to show an AlertDialog.

But I get the error: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application

I am also attaching snapshot of my Log to this Question.

```
 if(!mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)&& !mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)){

                Log.d("TrackingService","H: Exception after this");

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setMessage("Your GPS seems to be disabled, do you want to enable it?")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, final int id) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog,  final int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();
            }
```

[image]

Comment: You can't control GUI on service, the best thing you can do is to start a new Activity and make it look like a Dialog. Cheers!

Comment: @user2652394 does this have to be an activity or can it just be an XML layout?

Comment: is there any activity from which you are starting your service.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I have this problem but now is `solved` , if you want *really* run an alertDialog from a service , you should config  dialog as **System Alert** and remember to add permission in your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
```

/Here is the sample code:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx);
builder.setTitle("Test dialog");
builder.setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
builder.setMessage("Content");
builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
        //Do something
        dialog.dismiss();
   }
});
builder.setNegativeButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
});
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
alert.show();
```

Comment: Looks like you have an extra close paren for builder.setTitle() and a missing close bracket for builder.setPositiveButton.onClick().

Comment: how to config dialog as System Alert?

Answer (score 4):

You should keep some of the things in your mind while creating your gui:

1. All time consuming non gui work should be done in background (using asyncTask, Services, Threads etc).
2. GUI(like views and other graphical objects) should always be created and updated from UIthreads.

So create and displaying dialog is a UI work so it should be in UI thread. To run any code in UI thread you can use different methods like:

1. You can use runOnUiThread to run a piece of code in UI thread.
2. You can use messageHandler.
3. You can use Broadcast sender and receiver.

I think for your case runOnUiThread is best So use

```
runOnUiThread (new Runnable() {
                public void run ()
                {
                    // WRITE YOUR PIECE OF CODE HERE TO UPDATE OR CREATE GUI.
                }
            });
```

To understand the concept this can help you:

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html

To create broadcast you can use:

Step 1: Create a broadcast receiver in your activity from where you are starting your service.

```
   BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().equals("create_dialog")) {
                // create your dialog here.
            }
        }
    };
```

Step 2: Register your receiver after creating your broadcast receiver.

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("create_dialog");
registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
```

Step 3: Send broadcast from your service to display dialog.

```
Intent intent = new Intent("create_dialog");
intent.putExtra("dialog_data", data_object to display in dialog);
SendBroadcast(intent);
```

I hope this can help you.

Comment: runOnUiThread this method is in Activity. But my service does not extend Activity. So how can I deal with this?

Comment: real thing is you cannot create your ui in non ui thread so you need to send broadcast from your service to your activity and there you can create your dialog.

Comment: This answer is incorrect.  What is commonly called the "UI thread" is actually just the application's main thread.  Unless you kick off your own threads, or you're using an IntentService, your service and your activity will both be running in the main thread.  You can also generate UIs directly from a service by accessing the WindowManager directly.  The actual limitation here is that you need to set the dialog's window type to display it from a service. Ziprox09 has given the right answer.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of creating a new transparent activity, Use the *SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW* permission to do this

```
public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent intent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View popup = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mypopup, null, false);
    CustomDialog dialog = new CustomDialog(ctx, popup );

    dialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);

    dialog.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.PauseDialogAnimation;
    dialog.show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog  = new AlertDialog.Builder(myContext);
```

Edit.

Sorry about no comment. Put Context which started your service like a instance in service and use it.

```
class SomeService 
{   
     private final Context myContext;
     public WebService(Context myContext) 
     {

        this.myContext= myContext;
     }

   public void showDialog()
   {
        AlertDialog d = new AlertDialog.Builder(myContext);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do UI stuff like showing an `AlertDialog` only in the UI thread.
And since your `service` is not running on the UI thread you are getting this exception.

Try using `runOnUiThread` to show the Alert:-

```
if(!mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)&& !mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)){

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

            public void run(){
                Log.d("TrackingService","H: Exception after this");

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setMessage("Your GPS seems to be disabled, do you want to enable it?")
                            .setCancelable(false)
                            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, final int id) {
                                    startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
                                }
                            })
                            .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog,  final int id) {
                                    dialog.cancel();
                                }
                            });
               AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
               alert.show();
            }

            });
}
```

Comment: runOnUiThread this method is in Activity. But my service does not extend Activity. So how can I deal with this?

Comment: frm where do u start ur service..from receiver?