# Display alert dialog wherever in application

Tags: android, performance, android-layout

Basically i am working on android app, problem i am facing is stated below.

1. I have to display latest version notification availability to user
2. i can able to process all these information means find the latest version and check the current installed version.
3. after i found installed version is old, i need to disp alert saying that 'please upgrade to latest version' while user using app
4. I implemented to display alert at the time of launching the app but it create weird to user as it keeps calling for latest version update if successful continue not display update alert.

I want to make user to keep using app by making update check call in the background then display alert dialog.

when i tried, alert requires context(activity) to display on window, when user using app i may not be knowing in which context(activity) he is around.

can you please guide me how well i can achieve this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- You can create a static instance of context, and set it on every activity you move... So you can know current activity whenever you need to display alert dialog. This is a bit tricky way...

2- You can create a service to check your application's version is old or not, then you can check how to display alert dialog from service [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19677984/1171484)... I think this is the way you should go though...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood right, but... have you tried doing the version check in the background, on a seperate thread?

With [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), for example. That way the check can go on while the user keeps using the application, and if there is a new version available, the AsyncTask can call an AlertDialog "from the background".

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement display dialog method. If you want to check something in background (i.e. in a Service) and display something to the user you can also use `LocalBroadcastManager` from android to passing data and events within your application. But you still have to have some code in every single Activity that you have in your application. This code must contain following parts:

method for showing dialog:

```
public void showNeedUpdateDialog(){...}
```

in `onReusme()` and `onPause()` you must register / unregister `BroadcastReceiver`