# Pass Context From Service to Non-Activity Class

Tags: android

I having Service class and non activity class. And I want to pass context from Service class to Non activity class.
Here is my code:

```
Service class;
method(Service.this)

Non Activity class;
method(Contex context)
```

And I'm getting "Dialog throwing `Unable to add window — token null is not for an application” with getApplication() as context`  this error. how to solve this?

Comment: is it alert that you want to show?

Comment: Well, the question is what do you want to do with your context?

Comment: Yeah..I want to show Alert Dialogue

Answer (score 1):

You can't show a dialog from the service.

if you really want to show a dialog.

try to start an Activity and set the Activity's Theme to Theme.Dialog.

When you need to change GUI from Service you cannot do it directly from service. Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19677984/3134215) for more guideline

Answer (score 1):

Essentially services are Android UI-less components, so you can't show anythings from within a service. However two options come in mind.

- **Toast:** Toasts can be shown from any contexts (Activity, service, ...)
- **[A dialog-looked activity](http://www.javabeat.net/dialog-activity-android/):** You can create an activity that looks like exactly a dialog (by applying dialog theme to it) and then show it from within a service.
  <sub>(@ahmad aghazadeh's answer)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

In order to display an `AlertDialog` or so you must have an `Activity` context reference and not an `Application` Context or `Service` Context. You could just pop a [Toast](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html) message with the Service Context as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

In service add this code

```
Intent dialogIntent = new Intent(this, myActivity.class);
dialogIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(dialogIntent);
```

in myActivity you call AlertDialog

Comment: You can this activity 
`<activity android:name=".SampleActivity" android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent">
...
</activity>`